# encode h5 file to base64 file

Tags: shell, base64

I just attended one machine learning online. And I supposed to use IBM cloud to run the program as the class suggests. However, I always got bad gateway timeout problem. So I downloaded the notebook and ran the problem. Still I need to convert the file to base64 format and upload the file as request. Here are the codes:

```
model.save("model.h5")  # upload this file to the grader in the next code block
```

To upload the exported model to the grader we first need to encode it based64, we are doing this using a shell command:

```
!base64 model.h5 > model.h5.base64
```

These work on the cloud, but at local machine it does not work. I got the error like:

```
'base64' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I don't know what is missing and please advise. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal, you could encode using [openssl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL), for example reading from STDIN

```
echo -n "hello world" | openssl enc -base64
```

If you have a file this could work:

```
openssl enc -base64 -in file.txt -out file.txt.enc
```

You could also try:

```
echo -n "hello world" | openssl base64
```

or

```
 openssl base64 -in file.txt -out file.txt.enc
```